# No sound in Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: freebsd, audio

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 14'' 100S IBR-14'' Intel Celeron CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz, 32GB SSD, 4GB RAM running FreeBSD 12.0.

I am trying to setup sound on it. I set it up in `/boot/loader.conf` as:

```
# load sound driver
snd_hda="YES"
# load mixer
mixer_enable="YES"
sound_load="YES"
```

However, when trying to playing sound both in youtube or in the command line, I get this error, either when trying to use the Speaker or the Headphones channel:

```
pcm0: chn_write(): pcm0:virtual:dsp0.vp0: play interrupt timeout, channel dead
```

or

```
pcm1: chn_write(): pcm1:virtual:dsp1.vp0: play interrupt timeout, channel dead
```

The mixer seems to be ok:

```
# mixer
Mixer vol  is currently set to 100:100
Mixer pcm  is currently set to 100:100
```

To see the available outputs:

```
$ cat /dev/sndstat
Installed devices:
pcm0: <Realtek ALC269 (Right Analog)> (play/rec)
pcm1: <Realtek ALC269 (Internal Analog)> (play/rec) default
pcm2: <Intel (0x2883) (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play)
No devices installed from userspace.
```

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the sound working, according to a similar [post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/52921/) in the FreeBSD forums, you have to do:

```
sudo sysctl dev.hdac.0.polling=1
```

After this change, the sound started working while using the headphone jack (Right Analog).

To output sound from the internal speakers (Internal Analog), I had to do:

```
sudo sysctl hw.snd.default_unit=1
```

To have these configurations at boot time, add them to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
dev.hdac.0.polling=1
hw.snd.default_unit=1
```

See also:

[FreeBSD: no automatic switching between sound in speaker and built-in headphones jack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361167/freebsd-no-automatic-switching-between-sound-in-speaker-and-built-in-headphones)